# Bootstrap buttons unresponsive

Tags: php

Fixing up my project for a github upload when I encountered a very bizzare thing. My bootstrap buttons only seem to work when there's an echo in the end of the echo for some reason

```
    $sheetID = $sheets[$count]['id'];
  echo '
  <div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class = "tableTitle col-12"> Visual representation of ' .$sheets[$count]['sheetName']. ' </div>

  <div class = "clearfix"> </div>

  <div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class = "row">
      <div class = "id col-4"> COMPANY ID </div>
      <div class = "name col-4"> NAME </div>
      <div class = "age col-4"> AGE </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  ';
  echo "<div class = 'tableContainer'> </div>";
  echo '<button type="button" class="btnShowPage btn btn-success" data-sheet="'.$sheetID.'">Show table</button>';

    echo $sheetID;    
}
```

The buttons are linked to AJAX functions as well, so if needed I'll post them as well, but I doubt the problem is from them.

Comment: What is the loop you talked about?

Comment: Oops, need to re-write the question. I appear to have gotten confused w/ my shitty version control. There's no loop - you upload the sheets from a file at the end of all the sheets using AJAX, so you don't upload the info to the DB everytime a new file is introduced